# Translating py to js for discord bot

Tags: javascript, python, discord

How would I be able to use this code from the photopicker discord bot into the java script equivalent? It picks an image at random and displays the image without the url link. I am looking for a way to do this in javascript.

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="I Chose..", colour=discord.Colour(0x278d89), )
embed.set_image(url=i_chose)
await bot.say(content="You asked me to pick a picture...", embed=embed)
```

[Sending an image without the link showing with discord library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49622374/sending-an-image-without-the-link-showing-with-discord-library)

I tried this method but it gives me [object Object] in Discord.